# Derivation of Hamilton’s equations

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

The general derivation of Hamilton’s equations involve the change in the hamiltonian and consequently the change in the Lagranian that is a function of q and q_dot, L(q,q_dot). This is shown in this simple video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXu6zIItnLM

When deriving Hamilton’s equations for q_dot and p_dot, the lagranian is only a function of q and q_dot but not time. Therefore the Lagranian used to derive Hamilton’s equations is time-independent as it appears. Does that means that Hamilton’s equations for q_dot and p_dot are only right for systems for which the lagranian is time-independent (and therefore the hamiltonian- or energy is conserved) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrange movement equations $(n)$ extracted from $L(q,\dot q,t)$ are equivalent to the $2n$ first order equations

$$
\cases{
\dot p = -H_q\\
\dot q = H_p
}
$$

with $H(p,q, t) = p\dot q-L(q,\dot q,t)$. This last equation is known as  the Legendre transform. Here $L(q,\dot q,t)$ and $H(p,q, t)$ are respectively the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian. Both can be non autonomous.

Comment: You should add that $p=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$ is used to eliminate $\dot q$. Or else you have to define $H$ as the convex support function $$H(p,q,t)=\max_{\dot q}(p\dot q-L(q,\dot q,t)).$$

Comment: Well observed! Thanks.